# Passing URL Parameter to Drop Down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, url, simple-form

I have a simple form:

```
 <%= f.input :type, :required => true, :collection => ["Nonprofit","School","Company"], :hint => "Note: nonprofits will need to provide proof of nonprofit status", :input_html => { :value => params['type'] } %>
 <%= f.input :name, :label => "Organization" %>
 <%= f.input :first_name  %>
 <%= f.input :last_name %>
 <%= f.input :email %>
```

A user gets to this page through a url like http://www.website.com/org/signup?type=Company

I can use this format to enter a value into a field like name or email, but can't figure out how to pass the param to the drop down.

I've already tried a few things including changing :value to :selected or :option but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, figured it out! Posting here for future use.

```
<%= f.input :type, :required => true, :collection => ["Nonprofit","School","Company"], :hint => "Note: nonprofits will need to provide proof of nonprofit status", :selected => params['type'] %>
```

The trick is to drop the :input_html part and just use

```
:selected = > params['type']
```

Hope that helps someone in the future!